# Fastest way to save the image into SD card without using Async Task

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask

I am using Async task for downloading some other data, while that Async task executes I want to save the image from the url into the SD card. So what can be the fastest way or any alternative to save the image into sd card without using Async task. I have searched on the Google and stackoverflow, but can't find the appropriate solution.

Comment: `but can't find the appropriate solution` but the appropriate solution is to use asynctask,

Comment: @meda: So thereis one async task going on already, starting another async task won't be a problem?

Comment: No. You can start several paralles AsyncTasks, so parallelizing your code execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
touchView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = touchView.getDrawingCache();
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/MultiTouchView_Image.png");
                if (file.exists())
                    file.delete();
                try {
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
                    ostream.close();
                    touchView.invalidate();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Save fail!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Save successfull!");
                    touchView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                    touchView.invalidate();
                }
```

TouchView : The View you want to save to image.

Comment: hey sorry, but I can't get your solution, I want to save the image from the url into the sd card.